# layoutAnimation doesn't work when called from useEffect() hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im trying to trigger an animation from the useEffect() hook, It has a dependency so that it doesn't loop.

this is what gets called inside useEffect

```
const toggleDrawerAnimation=()=>{
        console.log('started next animation')
        LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
        setDrawerPosition(drawerPosition === "bottom" ? "top" : "bottom")
};

// and a snippet of my drawer component
<View style={[styles.optionsMenuContainer,drawerPosition === "bottom"? null: styles.fading ]}>
```

The animation does work, but it's instant.
I tried calling the same code but using a buttonPress instead of useEffect(), and it does animate smoothly.

this has been kicking my butt.
whats the issue? thanks for your help.

edit: here is my useEffect code block

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (init){
            console.log('first render')
            setInit(false)
        }
        else{
            console.log('second render')

            toggleDrawerAnimation()

        }
    },[init])
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you defining that function toggleDrawerAnimation above the useEffect hook and calling it within the useEffect callback? Or defining the function in the hook callback and never calling it?

Comment: @jacobPenney I defined the function toggleDrawerAnimation outside  the useEffect() code block. this function gets called by useEffect(),  and also gets called when I manually click the drawer to close

Comment: You said you're seeing it animate immediately, which is the expected behavior with how it's set up. The component renders, the useEffect callback is called. It updates `init`, which triggers a state propagation, which may or may not cause a full or partial re-render, after which the useEffect callback is once again called, triggering the animation. What's the desired behavior? It to trigger the animation after a delay? If so, I'd use a setTimeout in the useEffect callback with the desired delay time.

Comment: It's not really immediate, the above render and re-render just happens too quickly to perceive.

Comment: set timeout did it!

Answer (score 2):

You can useLayoutEffect to accomplish this, as other posters have mentioned the issue is that useEffect fires after the UI paints.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect

Answer (score 0):

Since `useEffect` callbacks are called *after* the render commit phase and hence after the render cycle, and `LayoutAnimation.configureNext` is meant to "prepare" the *next* render, it is already too late to call it inside of `useEffect`.

Unfortunately there is no current workaround for this, as `useEffect` is the only hook that is meant for tying in to the component lifecycle.

More info: [https://daveceddia.com/react-hook-after-render/#:~:text=Can%20you%20run%20a%20hook,it%20also%20runs%20after%20render](https://daveceddia.com/react-hook-after-render/#:%7E:text=Can%20you%20run%20a%20hook,it%20also%20runs%20after%20render)).